# How to calculate probabilities in a Bayesian network?

Tags: probability, statistical-inference, bayes-theorem, artificial-intelligence, bayesian-network

Consider the Bayesian network represented by the directed acyclic graph given below:

[image]

We are given the following probabilities:

- P(tampering) = 0.02
- P(fire) = 0.01
- P(alarm | fire ∧tampering) = 0.5
- P(alarm | fire ∧¬tampering) = 0.99
- P(alarm | ¬fire ∧tampering) = 0.85
- P(alarm | ¬fire ∧¬tampering) = 0.0001
- P(smoke | fire ) = 0.9
- P(smoke | ¬fire ) = 0.01
- P(leaving | alarm) = 0.88
- P(leaving | ¬alarm ) = 0.001
- P(report | leaving ) = 0.75
- P(report | ¬leaving ) = 0.01

**How do I calculate  the probability of P(smoke = T | report = T )?**

*Context:* This problem is from the following page: http://artint.info/html/ArtInt_148.html

- P(A|B) = probability of A given B
- P(A|B∧C) = probability of A given (B *and* C)
- P(A|¬D) = probability of A given (*not* D)
- A = T = A is True, i.e. the event A occurs

I am still confused by the formulae, even though I know the basic formula for Bayes' Theorem. When it comes to joint probability function it still seems confusing and I could use some of explanation to make it clear. Thank you very much in advance for your time and help.

Comment: Related questions: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1433543/probability-bayesian-network-problem, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1086047/bayesian-network-sprinkler-example

Comment: @William Before creating a tag, please propose the new tag on [meta] and explain why that tag would be useful. Too narrow tags aren't useful, and [tag:bayesian-network] may well be too narrow.

Comment: Sorry - I didn't know how the procedure was supposed to work. I agree that it may be too narrow -- graphical models might be more all-encompassing. These questions shouldn't be labeled as "Bayesian" or "network" though, since they are neither problems in pure graph theory nor strictly about Bayesian statistics (the same way a probability problem using measure theory shouldn't be tagged "real-analysis").

Comment: Also I would argue that the fact that 39.1% of the questions with the tag have been unanswered strongly suggests that the wrong people have been viewing questions of this type because they were incorrectly labelled.